# Show Server details via Python OpenStack API using the nova client

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, openstack, openstack-nova

I am trying to convert my BASH script to Python and am having difficulties in finding the equivalent code for *openstack server show* or *openstack server list --long*. I would like to know what host is my server currently located and use this information for a check before migrating it to another host.

Looking through the latest [novaclient documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/python-novaclient/latest/reference/api/index.html) and its [servers module](https://docs.openstack.org/python-novaclient/latest/reference/api/novaclient.v2.servers.html), I have found two potential commands that I was hoping would accomplish the task, but does not do so:

[list(detailed=True)](https://docs.openstack.org/python-novaclient/latest/reference/api/novaclient.v2.servers.html#novaclient.v2.servers.ServerManager.list)

- Gets a list servers
- detailed=True should return detailed server info (optional).
- **This returns a regular list of servers with their names.**

[get(server)](https://docs.openstack.org/python-novaclient/latest/reference/api/novaclient.v2.servers.html#novaclient.v2.servers.ServerManager.get)

- Get a server
- **This returns only the name of the server.**

I have been researching for the past two days, and I could not find the same / similar problem here in stack overflow so I have decided to ask and I am hoping that someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either list or get should be fine here.

As an example get would be used like this.

```
instance = nova_client.servers.get('my-server')
print(instance.name)
print(instance.addresses)
print(instance.status)
```

Or using list.

```
for instance in nova_client.servers.list():
    print(instance.name)
    print(instance.addresses)
    print(instance.status)
```

If you want an easy way of understanding the type of data you can get, you can simply use the Python inbuilt [dir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir).

```
instance = nova_client.servers.get('my-server')
print(dir(instance))
```

Comment: Hi eanderson, using dir(), I was able to find the host attribute of the server. I also used the Python inbuilt getattr() to display it's value.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

'my-server' needs to be the id as in instance.id, the name of the server is not valid.
I cant yet comment, so i wrote an answer.